# Spring Boot does not auto init logger when using @Cacheable

Tags: caching, spring-boot, logging, kotlin

I'm seeing a weird behaviour. Whenever I annotate a method with:

```
@Cacheable("contacts")
```

(Main class is annotated with `@EnableCaching`)
I get this `logger` variable as `null` within any method:

```
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductCriteria::class.java)
```

If I take it out, it's not `null` anymore.
From my debugging, it seems that cglib is creating some class proxy to be able to offer caching. However, this proxy is not correctly initialized as it seems.

Is it by design, a limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: It is correctly initialized. A proxy has all fields not initialized, the actual object will have the fields initialized (at least in regular Java not sure if that would change with Kotlin in the mix). When having `final` methods (the default I believe in kotlin) this is problematic as final methods aren't proxied (the same applies to other non `public` methods).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. is there any workaround?

Comment: Why would there be a workaround? It is the expected behavior...

Comment: How can I do logging in a proxied class then?

Comment: The proxy is only for applying the advices, the logging should still work. If it doesn't it means you have `final` methods (which is basically a no-go with class based proxies). Either use interface based proxies or remove the `final` keyword (ie. `open fun` in Kotlin).